# Using cell value as table array value in VLOOKUP (No Macro)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Cell value of B6 = 'Trading Income

```
=VLOOKUP(B6,'\\myComp.myComp.com\abc\Treas\P&L\data\[DataUS.xls]Smith, Bob'!$A$1:$D$2000,2,FALSE)
```

This returns (5,555,529.00)

However, say I wanted to place

```
'\\myComp.myComp.com\abc\Treas\P&L\data\[DataUS.xls]Smith, Bob'!$A$1:$D$2000
```

in a cell (Lets say B7). How would I structure the VLOOKUP?
I tried:

```
VLOOKUP(B6, B7, 2, FALSE)
```

And it returns #N/A

Thank you

Comment: Also please note that I would like to solve this without needing to open the linked sheet. using the normal formula from the first code block works without the referenced sheet needing to be open. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks Tommy. Unfortunately in this case, since it involves a linked sheet, this seemed to be the most minimal and simple case I could state. I have already removed layers of complexity from the real world case it pertains to to get to the heart of the issue that I wish to replace the 2nd argument of VLOOKUP with a cell value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=VLOOKUP(B6;'\\myComp.myComp.com\abc\Treas\P&L\data\[DataUS.xls]Smith, Bob'!$A$1:$D$2000;2;FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. However, I am looking to replace the long referenced sheet with a cell value that contains the path (see the last block of code in my example)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `INDIRECT`, [see this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm).
In your case, use `INDIRECT(B7)` instead of `B7`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately as the https://support.office.com/en-SG/article/INDIRECT-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd states, "If ref_text refers to another workbook (an external reference), the other workbook must be open. If the source workbook is not open, INDIRECT returns the #REF! error value."

Comment: @DolemiteMofo - I did not see this additional requirement. In this case, you are likely bound to use a somewhat contrived macro to replicate the behavior of formulas like your first one: 1) including external references, 2) being able to keep the last computed value. You may even ask for opening the linked file/updating the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=VLOOKUP(B6, INDIRECT(B7), 2, FALSE)
```

Just ensure that cell `B7` contains the exact path i.e. written exactly in the same manner it is written in the formula.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately as the https://support.office.com/en-SG/article/INDIRECT-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd states, "If ref_text refers to another workbook (an external reference), the other workbook must be open. If the source workbook is not open, INDIRECT returns the #REF! error value."

Comment: Apologies my browser was not refreshed so did not see sancho.s response. However if you don’t want to open the source workbook, a possible solution is to use a macro.

Comment: Thank you EEM. I was hoping to explore non macro solutions before I added that layer of complexity. Are there any other options to accomplish this, or if using a linked sheet, it is either Indirect or macro?

Comment: Hi DolemiteMofo, have been trying some ideas but unfortunately they don't work without opening the source file. 
Now adding macros doesn't really increase the level of complexity, at least I have not seen any case in more than 3 decades of experience as yet, on the contrary a macro, if done correctly, macros increase efficiency, dependency and certainty of the results. (please see solutions proposed in a separated answer)

Answer (score 0):

Now adding macros doe
sn't really increase the level of complexity, at least I have not seen any case as yet. On the contrary a macro, if done correctly, increase efficiency, 
[image]dependency and certainty of the results.

I suggest this solution which includes macros, provides the simplicity and flexibility of building the link to external data using a *Name* to hold the *External Reference* created using user input, which is split in the different parts of the external link to make it easier changes i.e. *Path, Filename, Worksheet and Range*.

This includes the creation of five *Names* to handle the linked formula, *here is when you might feel like you got it right when mentioning “increasing the level of complexity”*, however we can use the power and flexibility of macros not only to produce the expected outcome in a report, analysis, etc.;  but also to build forms, reports, graphs, data, etc. and by using macros it also eliminates the need for insanity checks, which at times make us insane, providing and excellent tool to reinstate, review and even change the parameters of large projects when required.

The code provided below includes the creation of the *Names*, also the refresh the *Name* that holds the *External Link Reference* once the user changes any part of the external reference in the worksheet.

First we run this code to create the names (copy this in a module)

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub FmlLnk_WshAddNames()
Const kRowIni   As Byte = 2
Const kCol      As Byte = 3
Const kWshTrg   As String = "Sht(1)"
Dim aNames As Variant
aNames = fNames_Get
Dim WshTrg As Worksheet
Dim bRow As Byte
Dim b As Byte

    Set WshTrg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(kWshTrg)
    With WshTrg
        For b = 1 To UBound(aNames)
            bRow = IIf(b = 1, kRowIni, 1 + bRow)
            .Names.Add Name:=aNames(b), RefersTo:=.Cells(bRow, kCol)
            .Names(aNames(b)).Comment = "Name to create link to external range"
    Next: End With
End Sub

Function fNames_Get() As Variant
    fNames_Get = Array("_Path", "_Filename", "_Worksheet", "_Range")
End Function
```

Now that the Names to hold the parts of the external link are created we add the worksheet event to automatically update the name holding the External Link Reference (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff198331.aspx)

To go to the event procedures for the Worksheet that contains the formula right-click the sheet tab and click “View Code” on the shortcut menu.
Copy the code below in the Worksheet code

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal RngTrg As Range, bCancel As Boolean)
Const kFmlLnk As String = "_FmlLnk"
Dim aNames As Variant, vName As Variant
aNames = fNames_Get
Dim WshThs As Worksheet
Dim bLnkExt As Boolean
Dim sLnkExt As String

Set WshThs = RngTrg.Worksheet
With WshThs
    Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1

    Rem Validate ActiveCell
    bLnkExt = False
    For Each vName In aNames
        If .Names(vName).RefersToRange.Address = RngTrg.Address Then
            bLnkExt = True
            Exit For
    End If: Next

    Rem Reset Name Link External
    If bLnkExt Then

        Rem Built External Formula Link
        sLnkExt = "=" & Chr(39) & .Names(aNames(1)).RefersToRange.Value2 & _
            "[" & .Names(aNames(2)).RefersToRange.Value2 & "]" & _
            .Names(aNames(3)).RefersToRange.Value2 & Chr(39) & Chr(33) & _
            .Names(aNames(4)).RefersToRange.Value2

        Rem Add External Formula Link Name
        .Names.Add Name:=kFmlLnk, RefersTo:=sLnkExt
        .Names(kFmlLnk).Comment = "Name to link external range in Formula"
End If: End With
End Sub
```

This procedure will run every time the users double-clicks in any of the four Names created in the worksheets that holds the External Link Formula

The Formula to use the external link name is:

```
=VLOOKUP($B9,_FmlLnk,3,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response EEM. I will try to implement this over the next day or 2 and will give my feedback then (and hopefully accept this as the answer after it hopefully meets my needs) THANKS!!